# How can I execute bloc event continuously in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to follow user location continuously in my application. For this reason, I want to execute getLocaiton bloc event continuously in my main page. How can I do that?

**Here is the my getLocation event;**

```
  GetLocationState get initialState => GetLocationState(saveUserCurrentLocation: initialPosition );

  Stream<GetLocationState> mapEventToState(LocationEvent event) async*{

    if (event is GetLocation){

      userLocation.getLocation().then((l){
        currentLatLng = LatLng(l.latitude, l.longitude);

      });


      yield GetLocationState(saveUserCurrentLocation: currentLatLng);


    }
  }
```

**And this my my main page**

```
            initialCameraPosition:
                CameraPosition(target: initialPosition, zoom: 10),
            mapType: MapType.terrain,
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _locationBloc.add(GetLocation());
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

How can I run code continuously in the background, without using onPress event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `Timer` inside `initState()` (make you widget stateful if it isn't):

```
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), (){
      _locationBloc.add(GetLocation());
    });
```